# vba query csv files "could not find installable ISAM" error

Tags: vba

I intended to write a macro to query both csv and xml files using Access vba. I do not want to parse csv or xml to a temp table in Access.

```
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbConnectionString As String

dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
sourcefilepath & ";Extended Properties=""csv;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""

Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & sourceFileName
rs.Open strSQL, dbConnection, 3, 3
rs.Close
dbConnection.Close
```

I tried the code above and kept getting "could not find installable ISAM" error message.
I also tried:

```
dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
sourcefilefolder & ";Extended Properties=""txt;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
```

It didn't work, either. 
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _sourcefilepath & ";ExtendedProperties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""". It worked

Answer (score 0):

Click on Tools > References and scroll down to:

Microsoft ? (The question is to select which connection you decide to use.)

And select:

Microsoft ADO (version you want)

and

Microsoft OLE (version you want)

I have found it also helps to select: Microsoft DAO Jet 3.6 even when I don't plan to use it as it supports several older utilties I often call on.

Comment: Note: If you don't see these drivers then you'll need to run the Office install again and choose advanced setup to select and istall the missing ISAM drivers that support CSV.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. But I still get the same error message.